# In MacMail how to prevent mail being moved to the "Junk" folder

Tags: mac, email

I have tried to correct the issue by identifying each email as "Not Junk", to no avail. What other options are available?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Review this article: https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/reduce-junk-mail-mlhlp1065/mac

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are asking for. You can turn off junk email filtering by preferences -> junkmail and unchecking "enable junk mail" filtering.
In the same panel you can also tell it to mark it as junk and leave it in your inbox (not move it).